# Issue with Place Order button

Tags: magento-1.7

We have an issue with Purchase Order payment method. The problem is when you click the Place Order button at the end of the checkout, it briefly shows 'Submitting Order' then the message vanishes. Nothing happens, no order is created and you are not taken to the success page.

This started after installing the latest patch's for Magento and even after removing the installed patch's, the button still fails to work.

We have searched for a fix for this, but alas, none have worked for us yet.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is something wrong with the AJAX request that is done when the place order button is clicked.
You can use firebug to see the result of the AJAX request. It should be a JSON response. If it is not (or if the response says there was an error), it means something wrong with your call. You should check the [`Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php) in the `saveOrderAction`. That's the place you should start debugging.
My wild guess (I may be wrong on this) is that you are missing the form key when placing the order.
Check the file  `template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml` from your theme.
If you have this line:

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

replace it with

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```